# Swift - Refresh UITableView but keep current position in table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a planning app with Swift 2, which pulls the data from a remote server via an API. The data of the API is ordered by time. The app shows the data in the exact same order as the API returns.

Now, however, I have created a UITableView which can be pulled to refresh the data. I also have added the possibility to rearrange the data to the likings of the user. When the user refreshes the table however, the data will all be restored to the order of the returned API data.

My question is: how can I still refresh the data, but let the data keep the current position in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the order in which data is displayed by how you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath. The API doesn't control your UI.

If you choose to display the data in the order returned by the API, then yes, user will lose their custom arrangement when the table is reloaded.

If you want the user to control the order data is displayed, you will need to persist some information about the order so that you can keep that order when the table is reloaded.

In the simplest case, you could provide some default sort options that make sense for the kind of data you have. You might have a type or category value that makes sense to sort on. You would then only need to persist the sort options the user has chosen and sort your data when reloading the table.

If you want the user to have complete control over the order, then you need to persist that order and reapply it when the table is reloaded. This is considerably more challenging. Some options, from easiest to hardest:
1. You could persist the order locally using just an identifier that uniquely identifies each item.
2. You could persist all the data and the order locally.
3. You could persist the order on the server.